# Windows Embedded CE 6,0 Installation

Tags: embedded

I need to install the Windows Embedded CE 6.0 package that works with Visual Studio 2005 because I need to upgrade an old driver that runs under CE 6.0.  I understand that Microsoft does not support this CE package any longer and, in fact, they no longer provide the installation files for CE 6.0

Where can I get the Windows Embedded CE 6.0 installation files??? They can be in an ISO file or whatever format is available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right. By *package* you mean BSP (Board Support Package)?

If you are new to CE, you will need a brief explanation before get started.

The Windows CE 6.0 itself doesn't have exactly *installation files*. The runtime system is built through a toolkit called Platform Builder. As "input" for platform builder, you select which components your runtime image will have (including drivers) and as "output" is created a binary image of your system. You may transfer your runtime image to the device with a few different methods.

Regarding drivers, they usually are distributed through BSPs. BSPs are built by the device maker so you could check the device manufacturer site for BSPs, but you can give a try first on the supported packages search (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/downloads/board-support-packages-for-windows-embedded.aspx).

You can get the Platform Builder Toolkit with a Microsoft Authorized Embedded Distributor or through a MSDN subscription (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/how-to-buy-windows-embedded-compact-7.aspx). The Platform Builder for CE6 comes with a copy of VS2005.

Windows CE6 is currently at R3 (released in 2009) and it is supported (mainstream support) at least until 2014 (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-roadmap.aspx).

I strongly recommend you to take a look at least on http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-ce-6-for-developers-overview.aspx. I'm not much experienced with CE6 (few months) but my personal experience says that it's a long path to code drivers for CE.